# Are dependencies suffixed with -dev on linux only required during compilation, or are they required to run the program too?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, libraries, dependencies

One of the libraries that I am using to build a program on Linux (Ubuntu) says it requires the following dependencies to be installed:

- libgl1-mesa-dev
- libxi-dev
- libxcursor-dev
- libxrandr-dev
- libxinerama-dev

Are these only required to compile the library, or will other people running the program on other machines have to install them too?

Comment: It's hard to guess without knowing what that library is and how it's built. Eg if  `libgl1-mesa-dev` is needed at built-time, the resulting binary may have `libgl1-mesa-glx`, `libdrm2` and `libxfixes3` as run-time dependencies. Or not ;-)

Comment: And some libraries’ headers assume their dependencies’ headers are present too, which means the `-dev` packages are also necessary when building programs which use the “topmost” library, not just when building the library itself... (But not to run programs built using the library.)

Comment: Alright, so it depends on the library. Thanks for the information.